# How to specify namer & rotator through logging.config.dictConfig - FileHandler

Tags: python, logging, file-handling

I'm looking for the right way to specify **namer & rotator** for a **logging.handler.TimedRotatingFileHandler**.

Here is an example:

```py
import logging

logger_config = {
    "version": 1,
        "handlers": {
            "file": {
                "class": "logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
                "filename": "logs",
                "when": "S",
                "interval": 8,
                "enconding": "utf-8",
                "namer": "?",
                "rotator": "?",
            },
        },
        "root": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["file"]
        }
}
dictConfig(logger_config)
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this way using a custom factory in configuration dictionary (the example produces logging records on console and on rotating files in current directory)

```
import logging
import logging.config
import logging.handlers
import os
import gzip


class MyRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self
               , filename
               , mode='a'
               , maxBytes=0
               , backupCount=0
               , encoding=None
               , delay=False
               , rotator_namer=None
               , rotator_fun=None
                ):
        super().__init__(filename, mode, maxBytes, backupCount, encoding, delay)
        if rotator_namer!= None:
            self.namer = rotator_namer
        if rotator_fun!=None:
            self.rotator = rotator_fun

def set_logging():
    def rotator_namer(name):
        return name + ".gz"

    def rotator_fun(source, dest):
        with open(source, "rb") as sf:
            data = sf.read()
            compressed = gzip.compress(data, 9)
            with open(dest, "wb") as df:
                df.write(compressed)
        os.remove(source)

    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1
      , 'formatters': {
            'default_formatter' : {
                'class': 'logging.Formatter'
              , 'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(processName)-10s %(message)s'
            }
        }
      , 'filters': { }
      , 'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
              , 'formatter': 'default_formatter'
              , 'filters': []
            }
          , 'rotate': {
                '()': MyRotatingFileHandler
              , 'filename': 'aalog'
              , 'maxBytes': 40
              , 'backupCount': 4
              , 'rotator_namer': rotator_namer
              , 'rotator_fun': rotator_fun
              , 'formatter': 'default_formatter'
              , 'filters': []
            }
        }
      , 'root': {
            'level': 'DEBUG'
          , 'handlers': ['console', 'rotate']
        }
    }
    logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
    return LOGGING

if __name__ == '__main__':
    set_logging()
    for n in range(40):
        logging.debug(f'Hello {n}')
```

Comment: This an interested way to solve the problem. I found a solution to do this, but I gonna try your solution. Thank a lot :)